# Creating a Map of a Map

Tags: scala

I'm very new to Scala so I apologize for asking stupid questions.  I'm coming from scripting languages such as python, perl, etc. that let you get away w/ a lot.

How do I create a map which contains a map?  In Python, I can create the following:

```
{ 'key': { 'data': 'value' }}
```

...or in perl

```
%hash = ( 'key' => ( 'data' => 'value' ));
```

Also, what is the difference between Map and scala.collection.mutable/immutable.Map, or is there a difference?

Comment: Just a note: on statically typed languages, maps of maps are much rarer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly more simple way to create a map of maps:

```
Map("german"  -> Map(1 -> "eins", 2 -> "two"),
    "english" -> Map(1 -> "one",  2 -> "two"))
```

This way you do not have to specify the type explicitly. Regarding the difference between immutable and mutable: Once you have created an immutable map, you cannot change it. You can only create a new map based on the old one with some of the elements changed.

Comment: This only works, if you know all entries at at initialization .

Answer (score 1):

In scala you can create a Map, if you want to fill it at creation, this way:

```
val mapa = Map(key1 -> value1, key2 -> value2)
```

Another way would be:

```
var mapb = Map[Key, Value]()
mapb += key1 -> value1
```

A map of maps could be created this way:

```
var mapOfMaps = Map[String, Map[Int, String]]()
mapOfMaps += ("english" -> Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two"))
mapOfMaps += ("french" -> Map(1 -> "un", 2 -> "deux"))
mapOfMaps += ("german" -> Map(1 -> "eins", 2 -> "zwei"))
```

Note that the inner Map is immutable in this example.

Comment: actually, the outer and the inner maps are both immutable, only the `mapOfMaps` reference isn't.

Comment: You are right, but I wanted him to notice, that is is not that easy to change an element in the inner Map.